# setAdapter undefined inside of AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

So I am making an app in which the MainActivity is based mainly around a ListView (in fact, that's all the MainActivity is.) So I extended my MainActivity from ListActivity. The problem is, I'm trying to update my UI Thread from inside of AsyncTask and it is giving me an error that says `The method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>) is not defined for the type MainActivity.GetContactInfo`

So I'm wondering how do I go about getting setAdapter defined. If I have to actually instantiate a ListView item, which ListView item would I instantiate? I am trying to make a custom layout for my ListView, so I am using a list_item xml file, while my activity_main.xml file has only a ListView in it, so I don't think I would grab that ListView to instantiate a ListView.

Any help on how to simple get setAdapter to work without needing to be attached to a ListView would be helpeful (since I extended my class from ListView I shouln't have to attach that to a ListView is how I see it.)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: AsyncTask code:

```
    private class GetContactInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ContactInfo[]> {

    @Override
    protected ContactInfo[] doInBackground(String... url) {
        URL json = null;

        try {
            json = new URL(url[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            contacts = mapper.readValue(json, ContactInfo[].class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return contacts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ContactInfo[] result) {
        int length = result.length;
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            names.add(result[i].getName());
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(local, R.layout.list_item, R.id.contactName, names);

        setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling setAdapter?

Comment: please post your code too

Comment: You should only update the UI from onPostExecute.  Why are you setting an adapter inside the async?

Comment: I am calling setAdapter from onPostExecute, which is inside of my AsyncTask, I'll edit my above post with my entire AsyncTask code.

Comment: @Simon you can update `UI` on `onPreExecute` too,

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan Yes, thanks for the correction.  I was thinking in context of the question.

Comment: This is all wrong.   You should create the adapter in the activity, bind it to the view, update the adapter in your async task, then use notifyDatasetChanged().  Many tutorials for this pattern on the web.  The simple answer to your question is that setAdapter() is a method of Activity, not of AsyncTask.

Comment: You can pass the instance of your activity in the constructor of GetContactInfo then call YourActivity.setAdapter.

Comment: Well I need to use the internet to get the actual array of strings, which is why I was creating it in the AsyncTask. I was having a lot of problems with bringing changes from AsyncTask into the main Activity code for some reason, so I just did it all in the AsyncTask.

Comment: what is the `local` ?

Comment: You're right about asynctask for getting the data but the only thing it should be doing is updating the adapter.  You don't "bring changes" from your adapter.  Just fill it, or update or whatever, then call notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: local is just my MainActivity. For some reason the Adapter constructor wasn't recognizing this, but I remember a while back when first learning about adapters it worked to have an instance of my MainActivity set to equal `this`.

I've never heard of notifyDatasetChanged, let me Google that really quickly and try that.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: you can use `MainActivity.this` instead of `local`, i don't see anywhere that you initialize `local`. this is not recognizable because you are in `AsyncTask` class not in your activty

Comment: Yeah a lot of the un-instantiated classes are instantiated elsewhere as global variables then given an actual value later on. I should have mentioned that in the code as well.

Comment: `global variables`???  Bill, you need to do some studying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setAdapter() method belongs to a ListView object. If you have extended from a ListActivity, you need to use setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter). ListActivity defines the setListAdapter() method while the ListView object defines a setAdapter method.

Change setAdapter() to setListAdapter() and that will work.

Comment: That was a lot simpler than I thought, that worked like a charm.